# importing an Image from a web api to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-web-api

I am new to the web development world . I am trying to return a Bitmap Value from a web api to a javascript to be displayed on an HTML page but for some reason it is not doing so , here is my code :

in the webAPI :

```
    public Bitmap  gettestBitmap()
    {
        Bitmap theBM = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources._2_15_2013_5_08_48_PM);

        return theBM;
    }
```

in javascript , here is my code

```
var callstring = "api/Generator/gettestBitmap";
alert(callstring);
$.getJSON(callstring,
function (data) {
    alert(data);                                 
    anImage.dataSrc = data;
})
.fail(
function (jqXHR, textStatus, err)
{
    alert("All checks are correct, image was not      
           generated.\n jqXHR = " + jqXHR.responseText + "\n  
           textStatus=" + textStatus + " \n Error=" + err);});
```

the webAPI function gets called successfully and the data that comes back is `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and not the actual image

any clues how to fix this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Solution!!!!

simply do the following :

```
var callstring = "api/Generator/gettestBitmap";
 $("#anImage").attr("src", callstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to return a byte array instead which will now be base64 encoded before being sent to the client.

```
 public byte[] gettestBitmap()
    {
        var imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Properties.Resources._2_15_2013_5_08_48_PM);

    return imageBytes;
    }
```

You may want to change the image line as well.

```
anImage.attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + data); // if format is jpeg change image/png to image/jpeg
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , I tried the suggested code , at the line `theBM.Save(ms, theBM.RawFormat);` I get an exception :`{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: encoder"}` any reason ?

Comment: @user1415780 What format is the image in? is it on the file system? does Properties.Resources._2_15_2013_5_08_48_PM point to the image directly? i may need to modify the code a bit after you respond.

Comment: the image is in png format , it is saved in the project resources and yes it points to the image directly

Comment: but my plan in the future is to create a Bitmap image and return it

Comment: @user1415780 i don't think you can do that. javascript has no notion of what a Bitmap image is, so you won't be able to use it in your code. What you need to send is either the url or a stream of bytes. i'm modifying my code now to solve your issue.